# GitHub: How to list unmerged or rejected pull requests

Tags: github

How to search for **closed** AND **unmerged**/**rejected** pull requests in GitHub?

I've tried `is:pr is:closed -is:merged` and other similar queries without success.

Comment: And how is this related to coding problems?

Comment: @Arvo My question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as far as I understand.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry then, haven't long time read guidelines (:

Answer (score 1):

`is:closed is:unmerged` will do the same thing as `-is:merged` would